# Angularjs Cannot read property of undefined on function returning Object

Tags: angularjs, return-type

I have a function which I use to validate some fields in the frontend, this is being called using the ng-click directive. Inside the **$scope.validateAgainstStudent()** I am calling another function **getStudentObj(value)** which should return one of the 3 student objects.

Whatever I've tried so far is just not working. The error I get is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined**

```
$scope.student1 = {};
$scope.student2 = {};
$scope.student3 = {};

//This is being called from the frontend ng-click directive
$scope.validateAgainstStudent = function(value) {
            console.log(getStudentObj(value).firstName);
            if(getStudentObj(value).firstName==null || getStudentObj(value).lastName==null || getStudentObj(value).address==null){
                alert('Please fill out all required fields');
            } else{
                //do something
            }
        }
    };

//This should return the student object
function getStudentObj(value) {

        if(value==1){
            return $scope.student1;
        }
        if(value==2){
            return $scope.student2;
        }
        if(value==3){
            return $scope.student3;
        }

 };
```

I could however do something like this, without the help of the function **getStudentObj(value)** but I will endup with lots of duplicate code since the student object properties are the same. i.e firstName, lastName...etc

```
$scope.student1 = {};
$scope.student2 = {};
$scope.student3 = {};

//This is being called from the frontend ng-click directive
$scope.validateAgainstStudent = function(value) {

    if(value==1){
            if($scope.student1.firstName==null || $scope.student1.lastName==null || $scope.student1.title==null){
                alert('Please fill out all required fields');
            } else{
                //do something
            }
        }
    if(value==2){
            if($scope.student2.firstName==null || $scope.student2.lastName==null || $scope.student2.title==null){
                alert('Please fill out all required fields');
            } else{
                //do something
            }
        }
    if(value==2){
            if($scope.student3.firstName==null || $scope.student3.lastName==null || $scope.student3.title==null){
                alert('Please fill out all required fields');
            } else{
                //do something
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: From your first bit of code: $scope.student1 = {}; then you make a call to the getStudentObj(value) which then returns student1/2/3, so where is the firstName on that object? That's probably why it's complaining...

Comment: @rrd the properties are being passed from the front end ng-model="student1.firstName". That's not the issue, as I explained on my 2nd snippet code - the other approach is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `value` is matching any of the `if` statements.  You could try adding a `console.log` to see if you can debug the issue.

```
//This should return the student object
function getStudentObj(value) {

        if(value==1){
            return $scope.student1;
        }
        if(value==2){
            return $scope.student2;
        }
        if(value==3){
            return $scope.student3;
        }

        console.log(value);
        return {};

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that you entered in getStudentObj(value) is different from 1, 2 and 3. For that reason getStudentObj return undefined. Make a console.log(value) in place of console.log(getStudentObj(value).firstName) to check value.